# Would it be possible to upgrade a Mac Pro 2010 5,1 with a W3530 to a W3670?

Tags: upgrade, mac-pro, xeon

I spent the last two hours trying to find a solid answer to this and come up empty-handed.

They share the same socket, same memory speed... I'm just not sure if the system will be able to handle the additional cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a report](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/archives/apr11/042011.html) from someone who carried out the exact same upgrade you're contemplating. Seems to have worked out fine, and produced a real improvement.

Comment: (FYI, that link was the first result when I googled "mac pro 2010 processor upgrades"...)

Comment: I just realized I looked through that earlier and it just didn't register I had seen it.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help!